# Who is this football player?

Tags: american-football

My brother pointed out that this football player strongly resembles me, but he doesn't know who it is.  Who is my doppelganger? It looks like the player in the rear (third person back, on the right) is wearing a Baltimore Ravens helmet.  Of course, they could be the opposing team.

[image]

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is a photo-finder question, a type of source/research request. Meta discussion in regards to photo-finder questions can be found [here](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/476/is-photo-finder-type-questions-on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be [Bruce Gradkowski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Gradkowski). He is Ben Roethlisberger's backup QB for the Pittsburgh Steelers.